# Edit a filled form and resubmit it with Ionic/Angular

Tags: android, node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I work on an Ionic mobile application.
I have a form in which I display data (that data is coming from a webservice). Is it possible to edit that form and then submit it to make it change ?
I tried to do that but didn't manage to edit the prefilled field (e.g delete a letter or a word, add some characters..) as if the edition was disabled.

Here is the **HTML** part (example of a textarea) :

```
<ion-list>
  
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label >Text area example</ion-label>
    <!-- com field comes from a webservice-->
    <ion-textarea  [(ngModel)]="editcom">{{com}}</ion-textarea>&nbsp;
  </ion-item>  
  
    <ion-button color="danger" (click)="editForm()" expand="block">OK</ion-button>

</ion-list>
```

Here is the **TS** part :

```
editForm(){
      console.log(this.editcom);
      this.service.postObjets(this.editcom); // send Data to Database
  }
```

I use that snippet to get data from a GIS WMS Webservice :

```
  let promise =   this.http.get(WMS_Webservice_URL).toPromise();
  await promise
  .then((data)=>{
    var com = (data['features'][0]['properties']['com']);
    this.com = com;
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    this.com = '';
  });
```

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you post the function which you get data from the server?

Comment: Ok, that's done !

Comment: I would suggest you try using FormControl/FormGroup.

Comment: When you are using ngmodel with two way binding, you don't need to use interpolation. Remove `{{com}}` and change `[(ngModel)]="com"`. Now any change in textarea, will be effected on `com`

Comment: Thank you very much @Qiimiia, my bad I forgot that use of two way binding.. I made the modification and it perfectly works. Great !

Comment: @Julien Glad to help. I'd really appreciate it if you give the answer I just posted an up vote and accept it as the answer to the question.

Comment: @Qiimiia : just posted the upvote and accepted the answer ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using two way binding, you don't need to use interpolation. Remove `{{com}}` and change `[(ngModel)]="com"`. Now any change in textarea, will be effected on `com`. You don't need `editcom` anymore.